# How can I find unused methods in a Ruby app?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have a Ruby app with a lot of classes/modules, and some of them are not used. Is there an easy way of finding out which?

I was thinking to do a profile, and then work with it's output. Any other ideas?

Comment: I use the NetBeans IDE and there's a feature to scan the site looking for unused variables / classes / methods. There are several profiler apps that can do the same thing though. Welcome to refactoring! :)

Comment: wasn't sure wether to edit this and add bounty, or create new Q... http://stackoverflow.com/q/9735307/252799

Answer (score 3):

A coverage tool, like rcov might help.

https://github.com/relevance/rcov

As you find methods that are not covered by tests, you should write tests for them or find out if they are used at all.

Removing unused methods is part of refactoring, if you have too many classes that can be a code smell that needs refactored also.

Comment: If you're worried about certain branches not being covered, you can also try heckle.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `raise` (or `raise Exception` if you don't want it caught) to the start of the suspect method. If nothing breaks, then it might not be in use (either that, or something's catching the exceptions).

Comment: brutally effective.  ...assuming that nobody did what my predecessor did and `rescue Exception` blindly...