# Is it possible to discover which classes are not used in a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In our project we had some "forgotten" classes lying around for quite some time.

Those classes were substituted by other ones but we forgot to delete them. Is there some automated way/tool to discover which classes are not being used in a Ruby {on Rails,} application?

Thanks !

Comment: This is tough to do via automation since Ruby is so dynamic; classes could be loaded based on class name, location, a symbol, the phase of the moon (literally), etc. Even instrumenting them to see if they're ever used or instantiated can be problematic if you don't have good code coverage in your tests.

Comment: If the application gets plenty of of traffic, you could instrument the suspect classes to write to a "deprecation log" (or include an easily-found deprecation tag), and monitor the log file over time. Registering no activity for a long while should mean, even if the class code is somehow reachable, that none of your regular users will miss them.

Comment: The thing is that we forgot to delete both the class and its tests. With that, we had pretty good coverage, but no hint that the class was useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been made a lot of times, but the best answers are compiled in here:

[Find unused code in a Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735307/find-unused-code-in-a-rails-app)

I, personally, liked the log parsing:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14161807

But in any case you can create your own logger extending ActiveRecord::Base to create an observer which stores in a database the most used modules. After a prudential time, you will be able to reverse find models that are not called even once.

There are other profesional tools (paid) that measures your app behaviour:

http://newrelic.com/

I've used this one in a project and did a great working measuring the controller usage. You might find it useful.